# Auto lisp to move all hatches and lines in every layer to a new layer with suffix _hatch and _line

Tags: automation, lisp, autocad, cad, autolisp

I want to do the following automatic workflow in AutoCAD lisp:

1. Retrieve and list all layer names present in the file
2. Iterate over the list and check if layer is empty. If empty continue to next iteration in list, if not continue to step 3.
3. Check if the layer name ends with _hatch or _line. If not create two new layers with the same name but with suffix _hatch and _line.
4. Select all lines in the layer and move to the new _line layer.
5. Select all hatches in the layer and move to the new _hatch layer.
6. Go to next iteration in list.

I tried using this code but AutoCAD keeps returning bad argument errors. Could any of you LISP experts help me out :).

Cheers!

```
(defun c:tennet_reorganizelayers ()
  (setq doc (vla-get-ActiveDocument (vlax-get-acad-object)))
  (setq layers (vla-get-Layers doc)
        layerlist (list)
        emptylayers (list))

  ; Retrieve and list all layer names present in the file
  (vlax-for layer layers
    (setq name (strcase (vla-get-Name layer)))
    (if (/= name "0")
      (setq layerlist (cons name layerlist))
    )
  )

  ; Iterate over the list and check if layer is empty
  (foreach layer layerlist
    (setq empty T)
    (vlax-for obj layers
      (if (and (= (vla-get-Layer obj) (tblsearch "LAYER" layer))
               (not (eq (vla-get-Handle obj) nil)))
        (setq empty nil)
      )
    )

    ; If empty continue to next iteration in list
    (if empty
      (setq emptylayers (cons layer emptylayers))

      ; If not continue to step 3
      (progn
        (setq layername layer)
        (if (/= (substr layername (- (strlen layername) 6)) "_hatch" )
          (setq hatchlayer (strcat layername "_hatch"))
        )
        (if (/= (substr layername (- (strlen layername) 5)) "_line" )
          (setq linelayer (strcat layername "_line"))
        ))

        ; Check if the layer name ends with _hatch or _line
        (vlax-for obj layers
          (if (= (vla-get-Layer obj) (tblsearch "LAYER" layer))
            (progn
              (setq objtype (vlax-variant-value (vla-get-ObjectName obj)))
              (if (= objtype "AcDbHatch")
                (if (/= (substr layername (- (strlen layername) 6)) "_hatch" )
                  (vlax-invoke-method obj 'Move (tblsearch "LAYER" hatchlayer))
                )
              )
              (if (= objtype "AcDbLine")
                (if (/= (substr layername (- (strlen layername) 5)) "_line" )
                  (vlax-invoke-method obj 'Move (tblsearch "LAYER" linelayer))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
    )
  )
  (princ "\nDone.")
)
```

Comment: Is the error only "bad argument errors"? is there any other indication that could help narrow the problem?

Comment: @coredump the main problem I'm facing now is that I cannot list all layers, and thus the layer list is always nil...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this line "vlax-for obj layers" you are trying to get objects from a layers collection object.

EDIT: In this part:

```
 ; Iterate over the list and check if layer is empty
  (foreach layer layerlist
    (setq empty T)
    (vlax-for obj layers
      (if (and (= (vla-get-Layer obj) (tblsearch "LAYER" layer))
```

you are mixing types of objects... the 'layers' object is the collection of layers retrieved from the line `(setq layers (vla-get-Layers doc)`, but you are looking for objects in that collection, `(vlax-for obj layers` and then `(vla-get-Layer obj)` which gets the layer of an object.
You should first retrieve the list of objects in the document.

By the way, there is a syntax error in your code. The `(if empty..` has too many arguments, the next `progn` has its closing parenthesis wrongly placed.

Comment: How does this answer the implied *How do I avoid `bad argument error`s?*?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
(defun c:tennet_reorganizelayers ( / % Layers lines hatches)
    (setq Layers (Layers:GetNames))
    (foreach % Layers   ; (setq % (car Layers))
        (if ( LayerIsEmpty % ) 
            nil ; (print (strcat "Layer: " % " is empty"))
            (progn 
                (if (not ( LayerNameIsCorrect %) )
                    (createCorectLayers %)
                )
                (setq lines(selectLinesOnLayer % ) )
                (moveToLayer lines (linesLayerName % ))
                (setq hatches(selectHatchesOnLayer % ) )
                (moveToLayer hatches (hatchesLayerName % ))
            )
        )
    )
)



(defun LayerNameIsCorrect ( LayerName / )
    (and (wcmatch LayerName "*_line")(wcmatch LayerName "*_hatch"))
)

(defun createCorectLayers ( LayerName / Layers )
    (setq Layers(vlax-get-property (GetThisDrawing) 'Layers ))  
    (vlax-invoke-method Layers 'Add (linesLayerName) )
    (vlax-invoke-method Layers 'Add (hatchesLayerName) )
)

(defun linesLayerName ( LayerName / )
    (strcat LayerName "_line" )
)
(defun hatchesLayerName ( LayerName / )
    (strcat LayerName "_hatch" )
)

(defun moveToLayer ( items LayerName / % )
    ( vlax-for % items
        (vlax-put-property % 'Layer LayerName )
    )
)

(defun selectLinesOnLayer ( layer / )
    (SSGet:ItemsOnLayer "LINE" layer)
)

(defun selectLinesOnLayer ( layer / )
    (SSGet:ItemsOnLayer "HATCH" layer)
)




 
 
(defun GetThisDrawing ( / ) 
    (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object) )
)

(defun Layers:GetNames (  / Layers % result)
    (setq Layers(vlax-get-property (GetThisDrawing) 'Layers ))  
    (vlax-for % Layers
        (setq result (append result(list (vlax-get-property % 'Name ))))
    )
    result
)


(defun SSGet:ByLayer ( LayerName / filter ssresult result )
    (setq filter (list (cons 8 LayerName) ) )
    (SSGet:ByFilter filter)
)

(defun SSGet:ByFilter ( filter / ssresult result )
    (setq ssresult (vl-catch-all-apply 'ssget (list "x" filter )))
    (if ssresult (progn
        (if (not (vl-catch-all-error-p ssresult)) (progn
            (setq result (SelSet:ToList ssresult ))
        ))
    ))
    result
)


(defun SSGet:ItemsOnLayer ( EntityType LayerName / filter ssresult result )
    (setq filter (list(cons -4  "<and") (cons 0  EntityType ) (cons 8 LayerName) (cons -4 "and>") ) )
    (SSGet:ByFilter filter)
    (setq ssresult (vl-catch-all-apply 'ssget (list "x" filter )))
    (if ssresult (progn
        (if (not (vl-catch-all-error-p ssresult)) (progn
            (setq result (SelSet:ToList ssresult ))
        ))
    ))
    result
)


(defun SelSet:ToList (selset / result i count)      
    (if selset (progn
        (setq count (sslength selset) )
        (setq i 0 )
        (repeat count
            (setq result (append result (list (vlax-ename->vla-object(ssname selset i) ) )))
            (setq i (1+ i ))
        )
    ))
 result
)

(defun LayerIsEmpty ( LayerName / filter ssresult  )
    (setq filter (list (cons 8 LayerName) ) )   ; (setq LayerName "0" )
    (setq ssresult (vl-catch-all-apply 'ssget (list "x" filter )))
    
    (cond
        ( (null ssresult ) t)
        ( ( = (vl-catch-all-error-p ssresult) t ) t)
        ( ( = (sslength ssresult) 0) t)
        ( t nil )
    )
)
```